# 301 Redirect passing parameters?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, prestashop

I have an old prestashop website `http://www.jeans-vintage.com/`
(in french). I want to do some 301 redirects to the new domain which is `http://www.destock-vintage.com/`.

So I modified **Jeans-Vintage htaccess** :

For example for the Men Polos category :

```
RedirectPermanent /70-polos http://www.destock-vintage.com/24-polos-vintage
```

The redirection is working you can test it here : `http://www.jeans-vintage.com/70-polos`

But when the new page loads here is the URL : `http://www.destock-vintage.com/24-polos-vintage?id_category=70`

Why do I have that `?id_category=70` ??

It's doing the exact same thing for every 301 redirect I'm trying...

I tried adding a "?" at the end of the redirect but this still doesn't work and shows :

`http://www.destock-vintage.com/24-polos-vintage?`

Any help would be appreciated !

Thanks guys :)

Comment: @the_pete  OP asks how get 301 redirect from one url to another with saving QUERY_STRING in single .htaccess .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on **Jeans-Vintage** htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.jeans-vintage\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^70-polos$ http://www.destock-vintage.com/24-polos-vintage? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Comment: Your solution worked too, wonder which one is better ? @anubhava has less lines ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mod_rewrite rules to strip off existing query string in `Jeans-Vintage htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^70-polos/?$ http://www.destock-vintage.com/24-polos-vintage? [R=301,NC,L]
```

`?` in the end strips off any existing query string.

Comment: its specify example. Works only in this case.If `71-polos` and `24-polos-vintage`. Write new rule?

Comment: You can have: `RewriteRule ^(70|71)-polos/?$ http://www.destock-vintage.com/24-polos-vintage? [R=301,NC,L]`

Comment: no. Its not a solution. OP asks how get 301 redirect from one url to another with saving QUERY_STRING.

Comment: I thought question is about stripping of original query string.

Comment: @anubhava I understood the same thing! :)